# C++ - How to reset the output stream manipulator flags

Tags: c++, manipulators

I've got a line of code that sets the fill value to a '-' character in my output, but need to reset the setfill flag to its default whitespace character. How do I do that?

```
cout << setw(14) << "  CHARGE/ROOM" << endl;
cout << setfill('-') << setw(11) << '-' << "  " << setw(15) << '-' << "   " << setw(11) << '-' << endl;
```

I thought this might work:

```
cout.unsetf(ios::manipulatorname) // Howerver I dont see a manipulator called setfill
```

Am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 34):

You can use [copyfmt](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/copyfmt/) to save cout's initial formatting.  Once finished with formatted output you can use it again to restore the default settings (*including fill character*).

```
{
    // save default formatting
    ios init(NULL);
    init.copyfmt(cout);

    // change formatting...
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(11) << '-' << "  ";
    cout << setw(15) << '-' << "   ";
    cout << setw(11) << '-' << endl;

    // restore default formatting
    cout.copyfmt(init);
}
```

Comment: Surprised nobody posted this earlier :) Rolling it into an RAII guard would be good though, in case an exception is thrown.  Have run into that issue in a logging framework.

Comment: Is that working on all systems? When I try it, my std::cout refuses to output anything after...ever!

Comment: this is great! it works also for std::hex

Comment: Here you have RAII simple impl: https://github.com/gelldur/gcpp/blob/master/src/gcpp/stream/StreamScopeFormat.hpp

Answer (score 31):

Have a look at the [Boost.IO_State_Savers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html), providing RAII-style scope guards for the flags of an iostream.

Example:

```
#include <boost/io/ios_state.hpp>

{
  boost::io::ios_all_saver guard(cout); // Saves current flags and format

  cout << setw(14) << "  CHARGE/ROOM" << endl;
  cout << setfill('-') << setw(11) << '-' << "  " << setw(15) << '-' << "   " << setw(11) << '-' << endl;
// dtor of guard here restores flags and formats
}
```

More specialized guards (for only fill, or width, or precision, etc... are also in the library. See the docs for details.

Comment: Great answer, should be the accepted one.

Comment: @gd1: Good answer, but not _great_, as I have to include Boost just to save the iostream flags.

Comment: @Isaac: in C++, it seems to me that you either use boost or end up reimplementing it, or wait for Boost.Something to be included in the standard.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `ios::fill()` function to set and restore the fill character instead.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/fill/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  char prev;

  cout.width (10);
  cout << 40 << endl;

  prev = cout.fill ('x');
  cout.width (10);
  cout << 40 << endl;

  cout.fill(prev);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but you need to do the same thing with width too.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually change the setfill flag to whatever you need it to be:

```
float number = 4.5;
cout << setfill('-');
cout << setw(11) << number << endl; // --------4.5
cout << setfill(' ');
cout << setw(11) << number << endl; // 4.5
```

Comment: That sets it to `' '`, which may or may not be the value it had before the first `setfill`.

Answer (score -2):

The null character will reset it back to the original state:
`setfill('\0')`

Comment: The original state is not necessarily the *previous* state. Besides, where is this claimed function of `'\0'` documented? All I can see are statements that `setfill()` just takes a `char`, with no special meaning for it. So you would be setting the fill character to `NUL`, which is not going to be what it originally was and is not going to be very useful at all. Or did I miss something in the Standard that makes it work?