# Where is my program's stdout's setbase(16) being called?

Tags: c++, gdb, cout

I have a somewhat large project that I am working on and I've discovered that someone added some code something similar to this:

```
std::cout << std::hex << variable << endl;
```

Aside from grepping through all the cout calls and manually looking at each one, is there a way to determine which offending cout line left the output stream's base as hex?

It seems that there's many different ways of setting the base so setting a breakpoint on a single function call doesn't seem to work. e.g.:

- `... << std::hex << ...`
- `... << setbase(16) << ...`
- `std::cout.setf ( std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield );`
- etc.

Is there any quick way i can tell what variable internally libstdc++ is using to store the base variable so i can set a data breakpoint on it?

### UPDATE:

After playing around with the code I was finally able to come up with the solution using in part both answers from perreal and Employed Russian.  Here is what I did:

First I added the following code inside my program so I could break and step into the function to get the address of the cout flags variable (_M_flags).

```
std::ios_base::fmtflags f;
f = std::cout.flags();
```

I set a breakpoint on the second line and stepped into the function and got the following libstdc++ code:

```
// [27.4.2.2] fmtflags state functions
/**
 *  @brief  Access to format flags.
 *  @return  The format control flags for both input and output
 */
fmtflags
flags() const
{ return _M_flags; }
```

Unfortunately gdb was unable to print out this variable but by going to the disassembly view I was able to pinpoint the address used by _M_flags:

```
 x0x84ca2e8 <std::ios_base::flags() const>                push   %ebp
 x0x84ca2e9 <std::ios_base::flags() const+1>              mov    %esp,%ebp
 x0x84ca2eb <std::ios_base::flags() const+3>              mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
>x0x84ca2ee <std::ios_base::flags() const+6>              mov    0xc(%eax),%eax 
 x0x84ca2f1 <std::ios_base::flags() const+9>              pop    %ebp
 x0x84ca2f2 <std::ios_base::flags() const+10>             ret
```

`0xc(%eax)` contained the address of _M_flags.

After I got the address, it was fairly trivial to set a conditional hardware watchpoint on it to see when the hex bit changes and track down the offending code.

It turns out a .so object loaded at runtime via dlopen was the culprit.

I ended up using Boost IO State Savers as referenced by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513625/c-how-to-reset-the-output-stream-manipulator-flags) to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any quick way i can tell what variable internally glibc is using to store the base variable so i can set a data breakpoint on it?

No: glibc is a `C` library and knows nothing about `std::cout`, which is a `C++` construct. Your question is about `libstdc++`, not about glibc.

Looking at libstdc++ [implementation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00968_source.html), it appears that you'll want to set a watchpoint on `std::cout._M_os._M_flags`. However, since various bits in flags are set many times during output operations, you'll probably want to make the watchpoint conditional on the `_S_hex (== 1<<3 == 8)` bit.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've changed the question to refer to libstdc++ instead of glibc.  I will try setting the watchpoint later today when I have a free minute and let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::ios_base::fmtflags f;
    f = std::cout.flags();
    std::cout << 21 << std::endl;
    std::cout << (f & std::cout.hex) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << 21 << std::endl;
    f = std::cout.flags();
    std::cout << (f & std::cout.hex) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
21
0
15
8
```

So it seems that you can use `f & std::cout.hex` as an expression or find out where that flag is stored in `std::cout`, which might be implementation dependent.