# std::cout formatting in Cpp 98 standard

Tags: c++, c++11, hex, iostream, fixed

Each of the following regards a distinctive `ostream`-format. How do I return it to default?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
    std::cout << "scientific:\n" << std::scientific;
    /*Cpp 11 standard only*/
    std::cout << " hexfloat: " << std::hexfloat << 0.01 << '\n';
    "The number 0.01 in default: " << std::defaultfloat << 0.01; }
}
```

As in :

```
std::set_default?;
```

Also how do I perform

```
hexfloat and defaultfloat
```

in Cpp 98 standard?

also what is the technical difference between setwidth and setprecision?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513625/c-how-to-reset-the-output-stream-manipulator-flags

Answer (score 2):

The default of the *mutually-exclusive* options [`std::fixed`, `std::scientific`, `std::hexfloat` and `std::defaultfloat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) is, you got it `std::defaultfloat`.

The default for [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) is `6`.

The exact effect of [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) must be looked up for each stream-inserter separately.

A replacement of `std::defaultfloat` for pre-C++11 is easy enough:

```
std::ios_base& defaultfloat(std::ios_base& str) {
    str.unsetf(std::ios_base::floatfield);
    return str;
}
```

Writing `std::hexfloat` is equally easy, but the stream-operators wouldn't know what to do with those flags.
Which is non-trivial to fix.

Comment: Woudln't it be `setf` instead of `unsetf`?

Comment: No? I don't want to set the flag, I want to unset it.

Answer (score 2):

The easy approach to restore the original format is to keep a stream without any modifications around and just use `copyfmt()`, e.g.:

```
int main() {
    std::ostream restore(0);

    restore.copyfmt(std::cout);
    std::cout.precision(8);
    std::cout.copyfmt(restore);
}
```

This approach will restore all the different formats, including the values stored with `pword()` and `iword()`. If you want to package this functionality as a `set_default` manipulator (you can't put it into namespace `std` as only implementers are allowed to put names in there), you'd use something like this:

```
template <typename cT, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>& set_default(std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>& out) {
    static std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits> dfault(0);
    out.copyfmt(dfault);
    return out;
}
```

It would be used like any of the other manipulators, e.g.:

```
std::cout << set_default;
```

You can just have one stream from which to restore the original values. Alternatively, you can keep the format of `std::cout` intact and rather create a separate stream using the same buffer but different formats, e.g.

```
std::ostream out(std::cout.rdbuf());
out.precision(8);
out << value;
```

This stream will write to the same stream as `std::cout` but use different formatting flags. You can even mix them as the streams don't store any characters directly: this is the job of the shared stream buffer:

```
std::cout << "value=";
out << value;
std::cout << '\n';
```

To answer your question about the behavior of, e.g., `defaultfloat`: these are just manipulator functions. If you want to use them without C++11 you can just define a corresponding function, e.g.:

```
template <typename cT, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>& defaultfloat(std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>& out) {
    out.unsetf(std::ios_base::floatfield);
    return out;
}
```

Comment: One thing: change typemame to typename in the first template function

Answer (score 1):

> How do I return if to default

```
auto oldflags = std::cout.flags(); 
auto oldwidth = std::cout.width(); 
auto oldprecision = std::cout.precision();
auto oldloc = std::cout.getloc();
auto oldfill = std::cout.fill();
//**************************************************
std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
std::cout << "scientific:\n" << std::scientific;
/*Cpp 11 standard only*/
std::cout << " hexfloat: " << std::hexfloat << 0.01 << '\n';
"The number 0.01 in default: " << std::defaultfloat << 0.01; 
//**********************************************************
std::cout.flags(oldflags); 
std::cout.width(oldwidth); 
std::cout.precision(oldprecision);
std::cout.imbue(oldloc);
std::cout.fill(oldfill);
```

It's kind of a pain in the butt.

> Also how do I perform hexfloat and defaultfloat in Cpp 98 standard?

Write similar functions yourself.  It's even more of a pain in the butt.

> what is the technical difference between setwidth and setprecision?

They do completely different things:

- width - The field width determines the **minimum number of characters** to be written in some output representations. If the standard width of the representation is shorter than the field width, the representation is padded with fill characters at a point determined by the format flag adjustfield (one of left, right or internal).
- precision - The floating-point precision determines the maximum number of digits to be written on insertion operations to express floating-point values. How this is interpreted depends on whether the floatfield format flag is set to a specific notation (either fixed or scientific) or it is unset (using the default notation, which is not necessarily equivalent to either fixed nor scientific). For the default locale:

  - Using the default floating-point notation, the precision field specifies the **maximum number of meaningful digits** to display in total counting both those before and those after the decimal point. Notice that it is not a minimum, and therefore it does not pad the displayed number with trailing zeros if the number can be displayed with less digits than the precision.
  - In both the fixed and scientific notations, the precision field specifies **exactly how many digits** to display after the decimal point, even if this includes trailing decimal zeros. The digits before the decimal point are not relevant for the precision in this case.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Well, yes, but the stream ignores those flags.  You'd have to write a standalone function that does the float->hex conversion yourself, which is non-trivial, and there's no way that I know of to "hook" it to those flags.

Comment: Well, in that case at least `std::defaultfloat` would still work.